# Custom shipping method

Tags: shipping-methods, magento-2.1.3

I have a custom module for shipping method, but not show in frontend. In backend show all options but in checkout run blank page.

My code is:

Config:

```
#app/code/Sistel/Transzuri/etc/config.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Magento/Store/etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <sistel_transzurishipping>
                <active>0</active>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
                <price>0</price>
                <model>Sistel\Transzuri\Model\Carrier\Transzurishipping</model>
                <name>Transzuri</name>
                <title>Transzuri</title>
                <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is not available. To use this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
            </sistel_transzurishipping>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

Model:

```
#app/code/Sistel/Transzuri/Model/Carrier/Transzurishipping.php
<?php

namespace Sistel\Transzuri\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;

/**
 * @category   MagePsycho
 * @package    MagePsycho_Customshipping
 * @author     magepsycho@gmail.com
 * @website    http://www.magepsycho.com
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
class Transzurishipping extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'sistel_transzurishipping';

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    protected $_rateMethodFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedLocalVariable)
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');

        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

        $result->append($method);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Get allowed shipping methods
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return [$this->_code => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }
}
```

System:

```
#app/code/Sistel/Transzuri/etc/adminhtml/system.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="carriers" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="sistel_transzurishipping" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Transzuri</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </field>
                <field id="name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Method Name</label>
                </field>
                <field id="price" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Shipping Cost</label>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="specificerrmsg" translate="label" type="textarea" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Displayed Error Message</label>
                </field>
                <field id="sallowspecific" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="90" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                    <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                    <source_model>Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="91" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                </field>
                <field id="showmethod" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="92" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Show Method if Not Applicable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="sort_order" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Sort Order</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change model in config.xml

```
<model>MagePsycho\Customshipping\Model\Carrier\Transzurishipping</model>
```

to

```
<model>Sistel\Transzuri\Model\Carrier\Transzurishipping</model>
```

Comment: I'm idiot. Sorry. I do cntrl + z and cntrl + y many times and I forggot change this other time. In time is working. Thank you very much

Comment: @AndresF if it helps you mark as accepted so it will be helpful to others

Comment: Thanks. I am new in the page and I don't know use the page well. I accept this comment